# Apache isn't loading PHP extensions

Tags: php, apache, php-extension

I installed(manually) Apache and PHP. I activated the curl extension from php.ini and It's working fine in PHP-CLI, but when I access PHP through browser with the help of Apache, curl(and any other) extension giving me errors that "{extension_function} is undefined"

PHP `7.2-64bit`

Apache `2.4`

```
// php.ini
extension_dir = "/server/php/ext"
...
extension=bz2
extension=curl
extension=fileinfo
;extension=gd2
;extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=interbase
;extension=ldap
;extension=mbstring
;extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop

// httpd.conf    
LoadModule php7_module "/server/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
<IfModule php7_module>
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
    PHPIniDir "/server/php"
</IfModule>
```

**Update**

I'm testing using this `var_dump(function_exists('curl_init'));` line of code ... 
when I run this line from php-cli, It's returning true.
When I run this line from a php file using browser, It's returning false.

[From PHP-CLI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2HOW.png)

[From browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbDqC.png)

[PHP File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0Xbf.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssl4R.png)

**Solved**

> 1. I used absolute paths everywhere(no relative path)(used forward slashes)
> 2. Added PHP to environment variables. I don't know why, but without this extensions aren't loading. I think php7 module for Apache requires php in environment.
> 3. Restarted the computer(Apache restart won't work)

I hope someone will find this helpful.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Does PHP work when using it via Apache (the browser)?

Comment: Often the PHP used within Apache uses a different `php.ini` file. Do you have one in the `apache\bin\ folder? If so edit that like you did the one used by PHP CLI

Comment: Yes, PHP working fine in browser. I ran phpinfo(); function from a php file and it's working fine.

Comment: So look at the parameter called `Loaded Configuration File` on the phpinfo output. That tells you where PHP Under Apache is getting its `php.ini` file from

Comment: There isn't any `php.ini` file inside `apache\bin` or any apache directory.

Comment: It's loading from `C:\server\php\php.ini` that exactly where I've enabled the curl lib.

Comment: Can you show us the complete error message please

Comment: I've updated the question for more detail.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply though :)

Comment: That does not actually help me, sorry

Comment: Do you need any other information ?

Comment: Did you try just trying to execute `curl_init()` then show us the error you get

Comment: I added error screen in the question. It's just a `function undefined` error.

Comment: You need to capture the phpinfo output for both PHP contexts and then compare it. That will lead you to why curl isn't available.

Comment: Also make sure that the user Apache is configured as, has read access to `C:\server\php`. By default Windows will assign directory permissions based on the logged in user. Where Apache is typically configured to run as a different user. When launching PHP through the Apache mod_php, PHP will be executed as the Apache user and not your currently logged in user. As opposed to the CLI where PHP will be executed as you, which more than likely has administrative privileges.

Comment: Another place to check is the `extension_dir` path in the `phpinfo()` which if loaded through CLI, should function fine by default when executed by Apache, but make sure it matches where your DLL files are stored. Additionally check your Apache error logs to see if there are any errors listed that can help troubleshoot.

Comment: Thank you very much for suggestions. I'm trying all these and will let you know the result.

Comment: issue has been fixed(updated the question). Thank you very much for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem - on Windows. After changing the path to the extension directory to an absolute path, it worked.

As suggested in the default php.ini (not working):

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

Turned into an absolute path (working)

```
extension_dir = "c:\amp\php\ext"
```

The strange thing is that this problem occurs on some machines / versions only. Could not nail it down. There is an official bug listed here:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74866

Comment: Thanks - changing `extension_dir` to an absolute path solved the mysterious load failures completely!

Comment: In my case the problem was that I had apache and php in user env vars only and not on system env vars. Adding those to system env vars fixed the problem.